# How to skip field serialization at JSON marshalling in DataSnap?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, datasnap

Is there a generic way to skip field serialization at JSON marshalling in Delphi XE2 DataSnap ?

```
TBizObjects = class
  DataObject: TDataObject; -- skip this field on serializaing descendants
end;

Model = class(TBizObject);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is quite easy but very well hidden. You should set the [`JSONMarshalled`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DBXJSONReflect.JSONMarshalled) class attribute to False for fields you don't want to serialize or deserialize.

Assume you have declared the following class you want to marshal:

```
type
  TPerson = class
  private
    FName: string;
    FSurname: string;
    FHeight: Integer;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;
```

In this declaration, only `FName` and `FHeight` will be serialized and deserialized, the `FSurname` will be omitted:

```
type
  TPerson = class
  private
    FName: string;
    [JSONMarshalled(False)]
    FSurname: string;
    FHeight: Integer;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;
```

Here you have some code to play with:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls, Data.DBXJSON, Data.DBXJSONReflect;

type
  TPerson = class
  private
    FName: string;
    // try to comment and uncomment the following line and see the result
    [JSONMarshalled(False)]
    FSurname: string;
    FHeight: Integer;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Person: TPerson;
  JSONString: string;
  JSONMarshal: TJSONMarshal;
  JSONUnMarshal: TJSONUnMarshal;
begin
  JSONMarshal := TJSONMarshal.Create(TJSONConverter.Create);
  try
    Person := TPerson.Create;
    try
      Person.FName := 'Petra';
      Person.FSurname := 'Kvitova';
      Person.FHeight := 183;

      JSONString := JSONMarshal.Marshal(Person).ToString;
      Memo1.Text := JSONString;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(Person);
    end;
  finally
    JSONMarshal.Free;
  end;

  JSONUnMarshal := TJSONUnMarshal.Create;
  try
    Person := JSONUnMarshal.Unmarshal(TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSONString)) as TPerson;
    try
      ShowMessage(
        'Name: ' + Person.FName + sLineBreak +
        'Surname: ' + Person.FSurname + sLineBreak +
        'Height: ' + IntToStr(Person.FHeight) + ' cm'
      );
    finally
      Person.Free;
    end;
  finally
    JSONUnMarshal.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```